# Why can't I meditate?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Whenever I try to meditate on the Whitcher 3 it says "you cannot do this now". Any help? I'm not on a horse or anything I'm just in the city of Novigrad and I can't meditate.

Answer (score 6):

Meditating inside cities is allowed, but some missions stops you from meditating. If you're not actively on a mission, it's a bug. Try to save and reload. If that fails, restart the game. If that fails as well, you probably need to load an older save.

Answer (score -2):

Go outside the city of Novigrad and try to meditate then.